# Deploying django project on DigitalOcean with apache and mod_wsgi and getting error as Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: django, apache, firebase, mod-wsgi, digital-ocean

Deploying django project on DigitalOcean with apache and mod_wsgi

I'm using

```
    Ubuntu 16.04
    apache 2.4
    python3.5.2
    django==1.11
    Firebase
```

Installed Apache : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev
    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
    sudo apt-get install aptitude
    sudo aptitude install apache-dev
    pip3 install mod-wsgi
```

Installed all pip3 modules
And apache is running

gave permission to www folder as

```
    sudo chown -R www-data:www-data www/
```

Created wsgi.py file as executable

```
    sudo chmod a+x wsgi.py
```

My wsgi.py file as

```
    import os
    import sys


    sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject')
    sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages')

    os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myproject.settings"
    #os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings") #also tried

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

apache config file 000-default.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.in
    ServerAlias mysite.in
    ServerAdmin myemail@abc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>                
    </Directory>                
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.in python-path=/var/www/myproject python-home=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite.in
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
    </VirtualHost>
```

Ran command after modifying 000-default.conf file

```
    sudo service apache2 reload
    sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
    sudo service apache2 reload
    sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

My project folder structure is

```
  .
  ├── __pycache__
  │   └── config.cpython-35.pyc
  ├── myproject
  │   ├── __init__.py
  │   ├── __pycache__
  │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
  │   │   └── settings.cpython-35.pyc
  │   ├── settings.py
  │   ├── urls.py
  │   └── wsgi.py
  ├── myprojectapp
  │   ├── admin.py
  │   ├── __init__.py
  │   ├── mail_html.py
  │   ├── migrations
  │   │   └── __init__.py
  │   ├── models.py
  │   ├── __pycache__
  │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
  │   │   └── models.cpython-35.pyc
  │   ├── tests.py
  │   ├── urls.py
  │   └── views.py
  ├── admin.json
  ├── config.py
  ├── db.sqlite3
  ├── firebasesdk-file.json
  ├── manage.py
  ├── requirements.txt
  └── test.py
```

Inside mysite_error.log file i'm getting error as

```
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.940530 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=6581): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.940823 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=6581): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.943517 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.943754 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.943897 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944040 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944133 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944260 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944349 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944464 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944561 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     app_config.import_models()
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944686 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944791 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944880 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.944945 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945013 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945087 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945161 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945245 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945367 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945461 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945608 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/var/www/myproject/myprojectapp/models.py", line 31, in <module>
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945712 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     cred = credentials.Certificate('../myproject/firebasesdk-file.json')
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945799 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 83, in __init__
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945863 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     with open(cert) as json_file:
  [Thu Oct 24 04:43:11.945979 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6581:tid 139660427339520] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../myproject/firebasesdk-file.json'
```

I also have firebasesdk-file.json inside my project

Also tried with virtualenvironment

Where i have created venv and installed all pip3 modules for python3.5.2 inside venv

Changed wsgi.py and 000-default.conf files with respect to venv
nothing helped with vitualenvironment

How to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: here `../myproject/firebasesdk-file.json` instead relative path give full path and try again you wil get correct path by `pwd` in `firebasesdk-file.json` file directory

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Thanks. this worked for me. 
Any idea about adding frontend alias and backend alias hosting in apache?

Comment: You want to add dns? Or you want to point to backend or frontend server?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I have same server where i'm deploying django and bootstrap as frontend code.
If i point to www.mysite.in then my apache config would be `Alias / /var/www/html/frontend/` but I'm also using WSGIScriptAlias as `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py` so both are pointing to same alias.

Comment: Your front end and backend are same you dont need extra alias for front end.  Just put your domain name in apache config specify static files and project root you are done

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari my backend path is `/var/www/myproject` and frontend path is `/var/www/html/frontend`. Both are in different directories due to this i guess i need to mention as different alias. check my backend folder tree as i have mentioned earlier.

Comment: Why did not you use django-templates? How you are routing then?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari i have not used django-templates in this application due to that i have queries regarding deploying two different stack into apache server.

Comment: I have some problems in digitalocean..ple if you known about solutions share with I need help ...

Answer (score 0):

can you check permissions of wsgi.py, if not executable you can try:

```
sudo chmod a+x /var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `python-home` should point to the python binary, on the command line type `which python3` the output should be something like `/usr/bin/python3` but may be different in your installation try changing the `python-home` to that.